# I don't understand this quicksort implementation

Tags: c++, duplicates, quicksort, element

I have a code for quicksort in C++ that works perfectly for an array of non-unique elements. I'm sure that a lot of people here knows it, but, who does understand it? Let me explain myself better. This is the code:

```
void quicksort(int a[], int first, int last){
    int i,j;
    int pivot;

    if((last -first + 1) <= 1) return;

    pivot = a[(first+last) / 2];
    i = first;
    j = last;

    while(i <= j){
        while(a[i] < pivot) i++;
        while(a[j] > pivot) j--;

        if(i <= j){
            //SWAP
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;

            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    quicksort(a, first, j);
    quicksort(a,i, last);
}
```

So, i understand everything but the if on the swap. Can anyone tell me, mathematically, what is the exact case or set of cases where i > j  after the two inner whiles? I know specific cases for it, but what is the mathematical (or exact) property of them for happening?

Sorry for the crappy english, and thanks.

PD: Ignore in this case optimizations, or choosing the pivot and all that stuff, please.

Comment: This looks like C code, not C++ ?

Comment: I think that the swap function is from C++, isn't it?

Comment: In C++ there is `std::swap` but without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to know what implementation of swap is being used here.

Comment: I think it's not strictly C but okey, I edited the title, now can we go to the thick of it?

Comment: @PaulR Except for the use of the `swap()` function (Supposing its `std::swap()`), this is one example of good C and good C++ code at the same time.

Comment: Well if it were good C++ it would not be hard-coded for int - it would be templated to make it generic.

Comment: Well, I could change it, I only wanted to write it fast so I used std::swap(), yeah, let me edit it :3

Comment: @PaulR I only wanted this to be for didactic purposes. In fact, If I were really using this I would do an iterative version of the algorithm. And of course, I could do it templated, but I would have needed to think more, and as I said, I wanted to write it fast, as an "example" input for the quicksort.

Comment: Sure - my last comment was in reply to @Manu343726 who asserted that this was an example of "good C++" - you're free to write code however you like of course. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, when starting out, a[i] > pivot (so i is not changed) and a[j] > pivot for all j until a[j] = pivot, the next iteration of the loop will result in a situation where j < i.

To illustrate...

Take the following array:

```
int a[] = [10, 7, 2, 6, 3];
```

On the first call of quicksort, with first being 0 and last being 4 (last index in the array), pivot will be a[2] = 2. In the first iteration if the while loop, a[0] > 2, so i is not changed. a[4] > 2, j--, a[3] > 2, j--, a[2] = 2, now we hit the if statement. 0 <= 2, so we swap a[0] and a[2] and execute i++ and j--.

Now the array looks like this:

```
[2, 7, 10, 6, 3]
```

with i = 1 and j = 1. a[i] > 2, so i is not changed. a[j] > 2, so j--, j now is 0. a[j] is not greater than 2 (since it is 2), and j stays at 0. Now, we have i = 1 and j = 0, or i > j.

If you notice, the 2 is in it's "sorted" position and does not need to be moved anymore. Also, the pivot was the smallest element in the array. Hope that helps you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `j` start at either end of the array until they find a value that is greater than the pivot (`a[i]`) and less than the pivot (`a[j]`). When two such values are found they are swapped locations so you end up with an array where after the loop `i` to the end are greater than the pivot, and the beginning to `j` is less than the pivot. Than we recurse on these two sub arrays.

`i>j` when the list is done being divided by the pivot value. `i` and `j` have covered every value in the array to make sure it is on the correct side of the pivot. This could happen right in the middle of the array or after only one value being swapped depending on where the pivot value is in the list. The pivot could be the largest or the smallest value, or it could be right in the middle of the list of values.